# PrestaShop: Get value of select menu

Tags: prestashop

Is there any possible way to get a selected value in [Prestashop](http://prestashop.com) **without** javascript? I tryed with Tools::getValue() but it doesn't work...

```
<select name="selectPosition" id="selectPosition">
    <option value="0">---</option>
        <option value="1">'.$this->l('Left').'</option>
        <option value="2">'.$this->l('Right').'</option>
</select>
```

Best regards,
George!

Comment: Not very sure what you;re asking here - do you mean get the value when the selection changes, or after the form is submitted (e.g. in a Controller or module)?

Comment: I wanted to get value of select menu when it is submitted in the module but I get it with $_POST['selectPosition']; and everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Tools::getValue checks is value is in POST or in GET, just pass the value you want to check ad param

```
if (Tools::getValue('selectPosition') {
    //make something
}
```